# Why can I not return List<Entry> when the return type is IEnumerable<IEntry>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have:

```
interface IEntry {}

class Entry : IEntry {}
```

Why is it that I cannot do this?

```
IEnumerable<IEntry> func()
{
    return new List<Entry>();
}
```

Doesn't the returned object satisfy all the type requirements?

Comment: What version of .NET you talk, prior 4.0 or no? Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796223.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is only available in .net 4

in earlier versions you can:

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<IEntry> func()
{
    return new List<Entry>().Cast<IEntry>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# (and .Net) 4.0 introduced the concept of [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) in generic type parameters (including [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx)), which allows the compiler to implicitly convert statements like this.

When defining your own generic types, you can declare types as covariant or contravariant using the [`in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) and [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) keywords, respectively.